# Rails - Issue with gem install rails, Installing Neo4j

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, neo4j

Updates:

Running bundle install on my old app gives the following errors:

> Installing pg (0.12.2)
>
> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>    c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb
> ```
>
> NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby >or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.
>
> (root) at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
>    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
>     (root) at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.r
>   b:1
>     (root) at extconf.rb:2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/share
>   d/gems/pg-0.12.2 for inspection.
>   Results logged to c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pg-0.12.2/
>   ext/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing pg (0.12.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.12.2'` succeeds before bundling.

Please advise.

---

I tried following the documentation here to install Neo4j: https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j%3A%3ARails-Introduction
I tried running 
 rails new myapp -m http://andreasronge.github.com/neo4j/rails.rb -O
but it gives me the following error:

```
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - =C:
            replace at org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1791
  with_original_env at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundl
er-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:207
     with_clean_env at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundl
er-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:211
     bundle_command at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railt
ies-4.0.0/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:271
         run_bundle at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railt
ies-4.0.0/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:277
         run_bundle at (eval):1
           __send__ at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1703
                run at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-
0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27
     invoke_command at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-
0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120
         invoke_all at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-
0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127
               each at org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1332
                map at org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:713
         invoke_all at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-
0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127
           dispatch at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-
0.18.1/lib/thor/group.rb:233
              start at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/thor-
0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439
             (root) at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railt
ies-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:43
            require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
             (root) at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom
_require.rb:1
            require at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom
_require.rb:55
            require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
             (root) at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railt
ies-4.0.0/lib/rails/cli.rb:15
             (root) at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom
_require.rb:1
               load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1073
             (root) at c:/Users/user/jruby-1.7.4/bin/rails:23
```

More importantly, a Rails 3.2.1 app that I previously built now doesn't work when I run rails server.  Could it have been that the

```
gem install rails
```

command broke my old app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try uninstalling all version of rails and reinstall using bundler

Comment: I uninstalled using 'gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx', and reinstalled only rails -v 3.2.1, but when I ran bundle install in my old app, it gives me the errors (see updates).